# Why is $AF \phi \lor \varphi$ not equivalent to $AF \phi \lor AF \varphi$?

Tags: logic, computation-tree-logic

Can someone explain to me (perhaps with an example) why $AF (\phi \lor \varphi)$ is not equivalent to $AF \phi \lor AF \varphi$. This seems counter-intuitive, because in any path where $\phi$ (or $\varphi$) is true, $\phi \lor \varphi$ is true as well. Or is my reasoning wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You also need to argue the other way around. "Each path has either $\psi$ or $\varphi$" is not the same as "either each path has $\psi$ or each path has $\varphi$".

[image]